# About accuracy in recommendation system

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

Hi I'm fresh in this field. I'm confused about the method of accuracy in a recommend algorithm. As I know, the rating matrix of users-items is sparse. I know I can use some algorithm to predict the missing values and the model like RMSE or MAE, but how to calculate the accuracy?

For some items, I don't know their real ratings. If I use 0, it would increase the error, isn't it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually hard to measure the accuracy of recommendation system compared to other machine learning models because we have no explicit method of telling whether the recommendations are precise or not. But there is a way to calculate the accuracy.

You will have the `users * items` matrix on which you are training your recommendation system.

If you assume that you have `10` users and `20` items. 
Your matrix will be of dimension `10 * 20`.

> What you can do is divide the matrix into training and testing
>   dataset.

For example, you can cut a `4 * 4` submatrix from the lower right end of `10 * 20` matrix. Train the recommendation system on the remaining matrix and then test it against `4 * 4` cut. 
You will have the expected output and the output of your system. Using them you can easily calculate `precision`, `recall`, and `F1 score`.

You should cut sub-matrices of various dimensions from various part of the matrix and then calculate the scores to find out how well your system performed overall.

Answer (score 0):

You can only check you accuracy on the items-users that you have data for them. It is better to test the accuracy on a validation set data that was not part of the training. 
Then you can check your accuracy using RMSE if this is a regression problem or AUC, log_loss, confusion matrix etc if this is classification problem. 
So, you just have to take the average error of the labeled items in your dataset.

Comment: hi, should I skip missing values when calculate the error?

Comment: yes. calculating the error should be done on a validation set that composed of samples with no missing values.

Answer (score 0):

Since in real datasets we have lots of missing values (sometimes even 90%), in order to have a better prediction, we usually replace the missing values by NA. And then we replace the NA with the average of user rating or the item rating or even the average of both. If you replace the missing values by 0, you underestimate those data which affect your result. 
For example, if we name our matrix ds:

```
#compute the user means
user.mean = matrix (rowMeans (ds, na.rm = T), nrow(ds) ,ncol(ds))
# replace the missing values (NA) with the user means
ds[is.na(ds)] = user.mean[is.na(ds)]
```